# How to get text position in svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg

right now I am working on Javascript library ( SVG.js ) I am stuck in getting position of text that appears dynamically suggestions required

Comment: what text is that? How and why does it dynamically appear? I think a [mcve] would be helpful here.

Comment: Basically that text is a user input value which is converted to svg

Comment: OK, show us how.